# Xcode bots for internationalization

Tags: internationalization, xcode9, xcode-server, xcode-bots

I'm currently trying to create bots to test my code in Xcode server, and I would like to test my app in several languages and regions, but I can't find a more convenient way to do this than creating one bot per language and region.  Is there a way to make one bot changing it's language between each test ?

Comment: Have you looked at documentation? Your question does not show any research you have done, any errors encountered when using functions, etc.

Comment: I looked at the [Xcode Server and Continuous Integration Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/xcode_guide-continuous_integration/ConfigureBots.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013292-CH9-SW1) to configure the bots, but only the triggers can perform functions, and there are run before or after an integration, not during.